# How to close an executable window Python

Tags: python, operating-system, subprocess, executable, exit

I will explain my problem :

For an application for my system I would like to know how to close an executable, like clicking on the pushbutton exit in the top rigth, as usual.
Context :
From a script python, I would like to run an executable. It is works fine with os.system or subrpocess popen. Moreover, I would like to know when this executable is close, it's works fine with subprocess check output.
And my problem : I would like to close the executable that I ran, but for many reasons on my system (the .exe send an snmp messages when it is closed by the button "close" in the top right to an another script, I can't change that), I have to close this executable as if I close manually the executable window.

To do self.p.terminate did'nt works.

Please, if you have any ideas, tell me.
Thanks for your answer,
Have a good day

My code is below :

```
import subprocess
import os
import sys,string,os
import threading 
import time 

class test():
    
    def __init__(self):
        pass
        
    def lancement(self):
        os.chdir('C:\dossier')
        #self.p = subprocess.Popen("C:\dossier\TEST.exe")
        os.system("C:\dossier\TEST.exe")
        
    def verification(self):
        while True :
            
            self.s = subprocess.check_output('tasklist', shell = True)
            
            if b"TEST.exe" not in self.s :
                print('Absent')
                
                break
            
            else : 
                print('toujours present')

    def fermeture(self):

        #os.close("C:\dossier\TEST.exe")
        self.p.terminate()

    def tests(self):
        ouais = threading.Thread(target =self.lancement)
        ouais.start()
        time.sleep(2) 
        testverif = threading.Thread(target = self.verification)
        testverif.start()
        #time.sleep(20) 
        #self.fermeture()
 
def main():
    testa = test()
    testa.tests()
main()
```

Comment: self.p doesn't seem to be declared in your code. Can you not get the process id and kill it ?

Comment: Indeed self.p is commented, but if I uncommented self.p, and self.fermeture, my executable closes (but only the executable, not the others scripts called by .exe), and it is not like I close manually, on pushbutton close.

Comment: I think you need to get the pid of the subprocess using the subprocess id of the command started. Then you need to start a new subprocess with ''ps', '--ppid', str(pid)]' and iterate over all id given in the output and kill them using os.kill

Comment: Thanks, But it will does not works. I tried with os.kill and the pid of process but it does not kill all the executable called by the parent. Also, I tried in Task Manager of Windows to "end the procesuss tree" (the python script will do the same things but automatically) and it is does not work either. I don't know if is really possible to do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is :

To close the executable like cliking on the close button is :

```
os.system("taskkill /im Test.exe")
```

This, closes the executable, the childrens and closes properly.